PHP Calculation of area between coordinates fails for non-square rectangles in WGS84 CRS
I have a PHP function designed to calculate the area between two coordinates using the WGS84 Coordinate Reference System (CRS). The function works correctly when the rectangle formed by the coordinates is closer to a square, but fails to provide accurate results when the rectangle is elongated either horizontally or vertically.
Here is the function in its current state:
    /**
 * Calculate the area between two coordinates in WGS84 CRS.
 * @param float $latitude1 - Latitude of the upper-left coordinate.
 * @param float $longitude1 - Longitude of the upper-left coordinate.
 * @param float $latitude2 - Latitude of the lower-right coordinate.
 * @param float $longitude2 - Longitude of the lower-right coordinate.
 * @return float - Area in square meters between the specified coordinates.
 */
public static function calculateArea(float $latitude1, float $longitude1, float $latitude2, float $longitude2): float
{
    //Funciona toda la función --> NO TOCAR
    $geographicCRS = Geographic3D::fromSRID(Geographic3D::EPSG_WGS_84); // WGS 84
    $topLeft = GeographicPoint::create($geographicCRS, new Degree($latitude1), new Degree($longitude1), new Metre(0), null); //new Length(0)
    $bottomLeft = GeographicPoint::create($geographicCRS, new Degree($latitude2), new Degree($longitude1),  new Metre(0), null);
    $topRight = GeographicPoint::create($geographicCRS, new Degree($latitude1), new Degree($longitude2),  new Metre(0), null);

    // Calcular la distancia horizontal (en metros)
    $distanceX = $topLeft->calculateDistance($topRight);

    // Calcular la distancia vertical (en metros)
    $distanceY = $topLeft->calculateDistance($bottomLeft);

    $distanceXKm = $distanceX->asMetres()->getValue() / 1000; // Convertir de metros a kilómetros
    $distanceYKm = $distanceY->asMetres()->getValue() / 1000; // Convertir de metros a kilómetros

    // Área = distanceXKm * distanceYKm
    $area = $distanceXKm * $distanceYKm;

    return $area;
}

I try too:
public static function calculateArea(float $latitude1, float $longitude1, float $latitude2, float $longitude2): float
    {
        // Earth's radius in kilometers
        $earthRadiusKm = 6371.0;

        // Convert degrees to radians
        $lat1Rad = deg2rad($latitude1);
        $lat2Rad = deg2rad($latitude2);
        $lon1Rad = deg2rad($longitude1);
        $lon2Rad = deg2rad($longitude2);

        // Calculate distances in Mercator projection
        $distanceX = $earthRadiusKm * abs($lon2Rad - $lon1Rad) * cos(($lat1Rad + $lat2Rad) / 2);
        $distanceY = $earthRadiusKm * abs($lat2Rad - $lat1Rad);

        // Calculate area in square kilometers
        $areaSquareKm = $distanceX * $distanceY;

        return $areaSquareKm;
    }

Problem Description:

The function accurately computes the area when the rectangle formed by the coordinates is close to a square.
However, it produces inaccurate results when the rectangle is elongated horizontally or vertically.

Additional Information:
I am using the following libraries in my PHP class for coordinate manipulation and conversion:
// Area calculation
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Geographic2D;
use PHPCoord\Geometry\LinearRing;
use PHPCoord\Geometry\Polygon;
use PHPCoord\Geometry\Position;
use PHPCoord\Point\GeographicPoint;
use PHPCoord\UnitOfMeasure\Angle\Degree;
use PHPCoord\UnitOfMeasure\Length\Metre;

// Coordinate conversion
use proj4php\Proj4php;
use proj4php\Proj;
use proj4php\Point;

Issue with Existing Solutions:
I have explored various solutions on Stack Overflow, including using the abs function to calculate dimensions, but none have provided accurate results, especially for non-square rectangles.
Request:
I am seeking a solution or alternative approach to accurately calculate the area between coordinates in a non-square rectangle using the WGS84 CRS. Ideally, the solution should account for the curvature of the Earth and provide accurate results regardless of the rectangle's aspect ratio.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Is it the same on normal cartesian geometry, with non squarish shapes? -- IMHO WGS84 is mostly irrelevant, but for large areas (and so your transformation "meter" is also inadeguate

You appear to calculating the area on a 2d projection. If you want the surface area of a region on a 3d sphere or oblate ellipsoid, you need to decide what the shape of the region you want is (bounded by given longitude and latitudes, or something else), and get the appropriate maths equations.

For the calculations that I must perform, that deviation of km2 is relevant. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking.

with:
$geographicCRS = Geographic3D::fromSRID(Geographic3D::EPSG_WGS_84); // WGS 84
$topLeft = GeographicPoint::create($geographicCRS, new Degree($latitude1), new Degree($longitude1), new Metre(0), null); //new Length(0)
$bottomLeft = GeographicPoint::create($geographicCRS, new Degree($latitude2), new Degree($longitude1),  new Metre(0), null);
$topRight = GeographicPoint::create($geographicCRS, new Degree($latitude1), new Degree($longitude2),  new Metre(0), null);
return: 4.962849310176806, not the 5.05 that must be
